# Can't find the default port of grunt-express-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-express-server

I can't find on which port is my express server running. As per the `gruntfile.js` configuration `3080` should be the default port. However I can't load `localhost:3080` after I do grunt serve.

This is the express configuration in `gruntfile.js`

```js
express: {
  options: {
    port: process.env.PORT || 3080
  },
  dev: {
    options: {
      script: 'app.js',
      debug: true
    }
  },
}
```

This is where I run grunt tasks in `gruntfile.js`:

```js
 grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'concurrent:server',
  'react',
  'less',
  'cssmin',
  'modify-indexjs',
  'express:dev',
  'open',
  'watch'

]);
```

This is the terminal log:

> `Running "serve" task`
>
> `>> ABHAY`
>
> `(node:1990) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.`
>
> `Running "clean:server" (clean) task`
>
> `Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task`
>
> `Running "react:files" (react) task`
>
> `Running "less:staging" (less) task`
>
> `>> 1 stylesheet created.`
>
> `Running "cssmin:target" (cssmin) task`
>
> `>> 1 file created. 224.26 kB → 165 kB`
>
> `Running "modify-indexjs" task`
>
> `Running "express:dev" (express) task`
>
> `Starting background Express server`
>
> `(node:1991) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: 'node --debug' and 'node --debug-brk' are invalid. Please use 'node --inspect' or 'node --inspect-brk' instead.`
>
> `Running "open:server" (open) task`
>
> `Running "watch" task`
>
> `Waiting...`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In your log, you have the following:

```
(node:1991) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: 'node --debug' and 'node
--debug-brk' are invalid. Please use 'node --inspect' or 'node --inspect-brk' instead.
```

This log means that your express:dev task tried to start node debug mode with flag --debug or --debug-brk, which are not supported by node versions >= 8.0. Then the server is not started.

What you can do is:

- Use a node version < 8.0 **(not recommended)**
- Disable debug in your express:dev task (setting debug to false) **(not recommended)**
- Upgrade or change your grunt express plugin. I was using grunt-express-server v0.4.17, upgrading it to v0.5.4 did the trick. **(recommended)**